# '.class error' in java

Tags: java, class

Hi there I am super new to coding and I keep getting a '.class' error when I try to run the code below. What am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class PeopleWeights {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
        userWeight = new int[5];
        int i = 0;

        userWeight[0] = 0;
        userWeight[1] = 5;
        userWeight[2] = 6;
        userWeight[3] = 7;
        userWeight[4] = 9;

        System.out.println("Enter weight 1: ");
        userWeight = scnr.nextInt[];

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "`userWeight = scnr.nextInt[];`" - Those are the wrong kind of brackets. Use `()`. That will fix one of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem

```
userWeight = scnr.nextInt[];
```

Solve this by:

```
userWeight[0] = scnr.nextInt();        //If you intended to change the first weight
```

**OR**

```
userWeight[1] = scnr.nextInt();        //If you intended to change the value of userWeight at index 1 (ie. the second userWeight)
```

Should work

PS: As a precaution do not import the Scanner class twice. Doing it once would be enough

Comment: It isn't a "precaution" to import only once, simply a cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not import packages more than once, now lets go to the actual "bugs".

Here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PeopleWeights {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
         int userWeight[] = new int[5];//You need to declare the type
         //of a variable, in this case its int name[]
         //because its an array of ints
         int i = 0;

         userWeight[0] = 0;
         userWeight[1] = 5;
         userWeight[2] = 6;
         userWeight[3] = 7;
         userWeight[4] = 9;

         System.out.println("Enter weight 1: ");
         userWeight[0] = scnr.nextInt();//I belive that you wanted to change
         // the first element of the array here.
         //Also nextInt() is a method you can't use nextInt[]
         //since it doesn't exists
         //return; You dont need it, because the method is void, thus it doesnt have to return anything.

    }

}
```

Also instead of this:

```
userWeight[0] = 0;
userWeight[1] = 5;
userWeight[2] = 6;
userWeight[3] = 7;
userWeight[4] = 9;
```

you can do this during the declaration of an array:

```
int userWeight[] = {0,5,6,7,9};//instantiate it with 5 integers
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood your intension and below are two possible ways to implement your thought:

I see you are giving values manually as userWeight[0]=0;
  If you wanna give manually I suggest not to go with scanner as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] userWeight={0, 5, 6,7,9};
         System.out.println("Weights are" +userWeight);//as you are giving values.
 }
```

If your intension is to get values at run time or from user, please follow below approach

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This is runtime and you need to enter input");

        int[] userWeight = new int[5];

            for (int i= 0; i < userWeight.length; i++) {
                userWeight[i] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(userWeight[i]);
            }
        }
```

PS:

I seen you are using util package import for two times, instead you may import all at once as import java.util.*;

Also you are trying to return. Please note for void methods its not need for return values. VOID excepts nothing in return.